# Groovy regex enhancement with conditional handling

Tags: regex, groovy

I need to enhance the regex for this application to satisfy the following.

The current regex looks like this

```
^[CDFGIMP][^_\\s]*_\\S*$
```

and the following code will be valid

```
C_12345
```

https://regex101.com/r/x2jUnt/2

it needs to be adapted to accept the following cases

- The new ReGex format should contain at least 2 underscores
- Exception: if the code begin with 'M' then it only must contain at least one underscore
- FKT12965_I20_GB215_01
- FKN16250_I26_GB215_03
- FKT12808_I09_GB215_01
- CQ425441_I09_GB214_01

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: (^[CDFGIP][^_\\s]*_\\S*$)(^[M][^_\\s]*) - tried to group it as such

Comment: (_){2} - something like this to ensure there are two underscores?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/RpJnAU/2

Comment: Its nearly there -- if it is CDFGIP - then it needs to contain at least TWO underscores

Comment: But it does require 2 underscores then. Check https://ideone.com/iFP1Jx. Note you do not need anchors and grouping if you use `==~` operator as it requires a full string match.

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight variation to the answer from @tim-yates and with comments:

```
def regex = /(?x)           # to enable whitespace and comments
             ^              # match from beginning
               (            # start of alternative 1
                 [CDFGIP]   # starts with one of CDFGIP
                 [^_\s]*    # zero or more non-underscore non-whitespace chars
                 _          # an underscore
                 [^_\s]*    # zero or more non-underscore non-whitespace chars
                 _          # an underscore
                 \S*        # zero or more non-whitespace chars
               |            # start of alternative 2
                 M          # starts with M
                 [^_\s]*    # zero or more non-underscore non-whitespace chars
                 _          # an underscore
                 \S*        # zero or more non-whitespace chars
               )            # end of alternatives
             $              # match to end
/

assert "FKT12965_I20_GB215_01".matches(regex)
assert "MKT12965_I20".matches(regex)
assert !"C_12345".matches(regex)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use this:

```
def regex = /^([CDFGIP][^_\s]+_[^_\s]+_\S+|M[^_\s]+_\S+)$/

assert "FKT12965_I20_GB215_01".matches(regex)
assert "MKT12965_I20".matches(regex)
assert !"C_12345".matches(regex)
```

I tend to prefer to pull this sort of thing out into actual code though, as the next person who has to look at this code will have thoughts of violence